# Absolute continuous measure with respect to Borel measure

Tags: measure-theory, dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

I am doing a course in ergodic theory and one of the difficult problems we got to prepare for the exam was:

*Does it exist a non-trivial measure which is absolutely continuous with respect to Borel measure?*

Does this mean that I have to find a finite measure $m$ that is absolutely continuous to Borel measure $\mu$ which is written as $m \ll \mu$, saying that $m$ is dominated by $\mu$?

Could this be related to how Borel measure $\mu$ is abs. cont. w.r.t. Lebesgue measure $\lambda$?

Comment: Are you translating from another language?. The question is very poorly worded.

Comment: Do you mean the problem itself or my question regarding the problem?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I am not sure I agree, what exactly would you like to change? At least I wouldn't say it is *very poorly* worded. Maybe you want to change "Does it..." to "Does there..."?

Comment: Hi Johan, welcome to the site. When you say "we got to prepare for the exam" do you mean "we got the opportunity to prepare in the *past*" or "we got to prepare for the upcoming exam"? People will tent to be reluctant to help if this is a pending question in an exam of yours. If it is *not*, I would encourage you to give a bit more context. In particular, if the exam is over you may already have some solution from your instructor which you can look at, and hence maybe produce a more concrete question for us to answer.

Comment: We cannot guess what you want to ask, but it shouldn't be what you write since the answer could be $m=\mu$.

Comment: As the question is posed: *Does it exist a measure which is absolutely continuous with respect to Borel measure?*, the answer is trivial: The Borel measure is absolutely continuous with respect to  the Borel measure.

Comment: @John B: This is just one of the problems we got so we could prepare for the exam, it is of course not a part of the exam itself.

Comment: @Ramiro: Well, this is one of the hard problems so I do not expect to get a complete answer, just a hint. I am very shure the lecturer wants us to find a non-trivial measure which is abs. cont. to Borel measure considering some of the questions we have previously discussed in the class are open problems.

Comment: @JohanFredrikAgerup , Let $f$ be any non-negative Borel measurable function, such that $\int f d\mu < \infty$. Define $m$ on the Borel $\sigma$-algebra by $m(E) = \int_E f d\mu$. Then $m$ is absolutely continuous with respect to $\mu$.

Comment: @JohanFredrikAgerup  What do you mean by "non-trivial measure"?

Comment: @Ramiro Thank you for your comment!I was just trying to refrace the question to disregard that your proposition (The Borel measure is absolutely continuous with respect to the Borel measure.) was a solution.

Comment: @JohanFredrikAgerup , Ok. So here is a non-trivial example: Let $f$ be any non-negative Borel measurable function, such that $\int f d\mu < \infty$. Define $m$ on the Borel $\sigma$-algebra by $m(E) = \int_E f d\mu$. Then $m$ is finite and absolutely continuous with respect to $\mu$.

Comment: @Ramiro Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, It is not very clear what would be "non trivial measure". By your comments it seems that you want to exclude the solution $m = \mu$.

Here is a rather general example: Let $f$ be any non-negative Borel measurable function, such that $\int f d\mu < \infty$. Define $m$ on the Borel $\sigma$-algebra by $m(E) = \int_E f d\mu$. Then $m$ is finite and absolutely continuous with respect to $\mu$.

If the measure space under consideration is such that its Borel $\sigma$-algebra is $\sigma$-finite, then, by Radon-Nikodym, the example above represents all possible finite measures $m$ that are absolutely continuous with respect to  $\mu$.